# How do I get Source Extractor to Analyze an Image?

Tags: fits

I'm relatively inexperienced in coding, so right now I'm just familiarizing myself with the basics of how to use SE, which I'll need to use in the near future.

At the moment I'm trying to get it to analyze a FITS file on my computer (which is a Mac). I'm sure this is something obvious, but I haven't been able to get it do that. Following the instructions in Chapters 6 and 7 of Source Extractor for Dummies (linked below), I input the following:

> sex MedSpiral_20deg_Serl2_.45_.fits.fits -c configuration_file.txt

And got the following error message:

> WARNING: configuration_file.txt not found, using internal defaults
>   ----- SExtractor 2.19.5 started on 2020-02-05 at 17:10:59 with 1 thread
>
> Setting catalog parameters
>   *ERROR*: can't read default.param

I then tried entering parameters manually:

> sex MedSpiral_20deg_Ser12_.45_.fits.fits -c configuration_file.txt -DETECT_TYPE CCD -MAG_ZEROPOINT 2.5 -PIXEL_SCALE 0 -SATUR_LEVEL 1 -SEEING_FWHM 1

And got the same error message. I tried referencing default.sex directly:

> sex MedSpiral_20deg_Ser12_.45_.fits.fits -c default.sex

And got the same error message again, substituting "configuration_file.txt not found" with "default.sex not found" (I checked that default.sex was on my computer, it is). The same thing happened when I tried to use default.param.

Here's the link to SE for Dummies (Chapter 6 begins on page 19):

http://astroa.physics.metu.edu.tr/MANUALS/sextractor/Guide2source_extractor.pdf

Comment: Is `configuration_file.txt` in your current working directory?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error (ERROR: can't read default.param) because the full path is not defined for default.param. I got it running as follows:

1. From the installation directory (/usr/share/source-extractor in Debian) copy default.sex, default.param and default.conv file to your working directory.
2. In default.sex enter the full path for the following keys:

   PARAMETERS_NAME  /home/han/test/default.param  # name of the file containing catalog contents

   FILTER_NAME      /home/han/test/default.conv   # name of the file containing the filter

   XSL_URL          file:///usr/share/source-extractor/sextractor.xsl
3. In default.param remove the # from the following keys (or more):

   NUMBER                   Running object number

   X_IMAGE_DBL              Object position along x (double precision)                [pixel]

   Y_IMAGE_DBL              Object position along y (double precision)                [pixel]
4. Execute the extractor like follows: (In Debian the executable is called source-extractor)

   source-extractor m84.fits -c /home/han/test/default.sex

The output will be in test.cat in your working directory (/home/han/test/)

Answer (score 0):

If you run the command "sex MedSpiral_20deg_Ser12_.45_fits.fits -c default.sex" within the config folder (within the sextractor folder), you will be able to run it.

However, I wonder how I can possibly run sextractor command from any folder in my computer?

Comment: Working on this now - you can specify custom locations with -PARAMETERS_NAME and -CATALOG_NAMES, etc.